# Can I import or require the Math functions so that it is unnecessary to prefix them with "Math." at each call?

Tags: javascript, alias

I do not want to have to say Math.floor(x), Math.sqrt(x), etc everywhere I call a Math function in javascript. Is there a way to import all the Math functions into the namespace so I don't need to do this? Perhaps some use of import or require?

Comment: `const floor = Math.floor` or `const {floor, sqrt} = Math`

Comment: Thanks! I am working in js, python, C# and Rust and I can't keep them all straight...

Comment: Add your suggestion as an answer and I will approve